# Speech_recognition

Tags: python, while, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Как сделать код в Speech_Recognition, чтобы, если он не мог распознать речь, он снова начинал слушать и распознавать речь, пока не сможет это сделать. Желательно, чтобы код работал с использованием "while".

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    mic_text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
print(mic_text)
```

Comment: в случае не  распознавания речи, наверняка, что-то возвращается функцией распознавания, пока это условие истинно, то продолжать слушать

Comment: А как именно мне это записать, типо: while че-то там == true:

Comment: Код покажи свой

Comment: Вот, но для полноты работы нужно еще установить PyAudio, попробуй сказать белеберду и будет ошибка, а надо чтобы код перезапускал код, пока не сможет вывести текст

Comment: Что выводит `mic_text` если текст не распознан?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\novik\Desktop\Тест\test_mic.py", line 6, in <module>
    mic_text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")

  File "C:\Users\novik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()

speech_recognition.UnknownValueError


Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код воспроизвести ваш не могу, к сожалению, но по идее будет так :

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
def get_speech():
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            mic_text = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
            print(mic_text)
            return True
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            return False

while True:
    value = get_speech()
    if value:
        break
    else:
        value = get_speech()
```

Comment: Почему-то после первого неправильного распознавания, последующие распознавание, сопровождается два раза

Comment: да, исправил код

Comment: Теперь появилось это SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: Я тут подумал и понял, а зачем мне тут использовать "while", когда можно сделать так..(Посмотри в коде исправления)

Comment: `while get_speech() is False:` -> `while not get_speech():` Но вообще переделайте лучше на `while True:` и внутри проверяйте возврат `get_speech()`, сейчас вы результат каждого второго вызова просто теряете и не проверяете.